# Use an activity output as the step name to get additional info in ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to capture error data in Azure Data Factory. When an error occurs in any activity I want to capture error information and pass it into another pipeline to do processing and storage. For example I capture error message through this dynamic expression:

```
@activity('Log_Execution').Error.message
```

and the activity name through this:

```
@activity('Log_Execution').Error.target
```

I am trying to find a way to combine these two so that I can pass in the expression to get the Activity Name into the expression to get the Error Message:

```
@activity(activity('Log_Execution').Error.target).Error.message
```

Where the inside of the activity translates to 'Log_Execution'. However I get the error code: `Only a single string literal argument is allowed inside the class clause.`

I have tried setting the Activity Name from the `Error.Target` output in a set variable activity and then using it as the input of the variable like this `@string(activity(variables('error_step')).Error.errorCode)` but I get the same error.

Is there a way to get around this so that I can dynamically get error information using the `Error.Target` expression.

Comment: Could you explain why it is needed to get the activity name `Log_Execution` from the expression `@activity('Log_Execution').Error.target` . This expression itself uses the same activity name only. Can you explain the requirement clearly with more details?